# Notify user if inputted text has more than 2 characters and no more than 15 characters

Tags: php

I am trying to notify the user if the text they entered into an input field is more than 2 characters and less than 15 characters using this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $text = $_POST['text'];
   if(!empty($text)) {
      if(!strlen($text) < 2 && (!strlen($text) > 15)) {
         echo 'More than 2 characters and no more than 15 characters';
      }
   }
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text" maxlength="15" pattern=".{2,15}" required title="Please enter a username with at least 2 characters and no more than 15." required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The problem is, the echo statement isn't being displayed when the `if` statement is correct.

Comment: You might want to change `!strlen($text) <2` to `strlen($text) >= 2` and so for the second condition

Comment: If I change both conditions to `strlen($text) >= 2`, won't they be the same?

Comment: Hm.. i think that this condition (and warning to user) would make more sense:   if(strlen($text) < 2 || strlen($text) > 15 ) (with your regex pattern given in html)

Comment: @sinisake Is there a difference between this solution and the answer below?

Comment: Yes, but anwer bellow does what you want...i am just not sure is there really need to give user warning if he entered desired length... (3,4...etc...) :)

Comment: @sinisake I would run a database query if the conditions or met, but it is more clearer in a question to put an echo example (and it also helps troubleshoot as you can see it).

Comment: Is min 2 and max 15? If so:  if (strlen($text) >= 2 && strlen($text) <= 15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proper condition:

```
if (strlen($text) > 2 && strlen($text) < 15) {
    echo 'More than 2 characters and no more than 15 characters';
}
```

Comment: Cheers u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

As per [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php), `!` has more precedence that `>` so this:

```
!strlen($text) > 15
```

... equals this:

```
(!strlen($text)) > 15 // Parenthesis added to make precedence obvious
```

I also suggest you switch to [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/mb_strlen) to make it multi-byte aware.